# How to check array integer value in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

i want to make check value function like below code.
enabled is true only if the integer array contains 5 or 16, otherwise enabled is false.
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 3):

Use the default `IntArray.any(predicate: (Int) -> Boolean) : Boolean` function to check it. Example:

```
@Test
fun intArray_containsElement() {
    val arrayTest = intArrayOf(1, 10, 50, 5, 6, 4, 3)
    val isEnable = arrayTest.any { it == 5 || it == 16 }
    assertEquals(true, isEnable) // Successfully
}
```

Comment: Ah, this is better than mine, because it only iterates the array once 

Answer (score 1):

*edit: As Duc Thang pointed out, using `any` is better because it only iterates the array once:*

```
val IntArray.enabled: Boolean get() = any { it == 5 || it == 16 }
```

Previous less efficient version:

```
val IntArray.enabled: Boolean get() = contains(5) || contains(16)
```

Test:

```
fun main() {
    println(intArrayOf(0).enabled)
    println(intArrayOf(0, 5).enabled)
    println(intArrayOf(1, 16).enabled)
    println(intArrayOf(5, 16).enabled)
    println(intArrayOf(19, 1000, 4).enabled)
}
```

Output:

```
false
true
true
true
false
```

Comment: thank u for your answer. but if array contain 3 enabled get false .

Comment: @dspark you didn't mention anything about 3 in your question.

Comment: I'm going to vote to close this as needs more details, as it's clear you didn't provide enough information for us to give you an acceptable answer. Please update the question.